# What is "Reference" that leads to the controller block?

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, controller

I am currently reading the textbook *Fundamentals of Power Electronics*, third edition, by Robert W. Maksimovic and Dragan Erickson. In the introduction, the authors say the following:

> Control is invariably required. It is nearly always desired to produce a well-regulated output voltage, in the presence of variations in the input voltage and load current. As illustrated in Fig. 1.2, a controller block is an integral part of any power processing system.
>
> [image]

What is "Reference" in figure 1.2, and how is it relevant in this context?

Comment: It's some "gold standard" that is considered to be accurate and not just precise. Something, in the best of all worlds, that comes from NIST or DIN. (Some kind of magical oracle that tells you what the great universe we live in considers to be, for example, exactly \$1.245000\:\text{V}\pm 300\:\text{nV}\$.)

Comment: @jonk Ok, I understand. So how does it actually fit into this context? Why do we actually need it here?

Comment: Well, there's that *feedback* thing that supposedly tells you what the output is, yes? And you have this magical oracle that tells you what \$1.245000\:\text{V}\$ happens to be (within some tiny error, we hope.) It can then apply some fiddle-factor, including some *feedforward* info -- say the differential expressing what direction the output appears to be changing and maybe even its acceleration too, and magically work out some kind of control to the converter that will mystically make *everthing work out right* in the end. All the truly good stuff is swept under that *controller* rug.

Comment: @jonk Ahh, I see. So it is basically the reference that allows the controller to act as a corrective mechanism for the switching converter?

Comment: Yup! That's it. It otherwise has no real idea. How does it know if the output is at the right voltage if it doesn't have a gold standard against which to measure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control system can operate in different ways depending whether the output must faithfully track a variable control input or must firmly keep a specific fixed output value while fighting incoming perturbations. An example for the first definition is a steering wheel imposing an angle to the car wheels via an electric drive: as the driver turns the wheel you want the car to smoothly turn and precisely follow the angle imposed by the driver. In this example, the setpoint is permanently varying while the output must track it. The second case designates a circuit in which the setpoint is fixed, imposing a fixed output variable. The output variable must remain regulated regardless of the perturbation the control system faces. A voltage regulator is the perfect example where the setpoint is the *reference* voltage and the output the voltage delivered to a load. The below sketch excerpted from my [2010 APEC](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf) seminar shows a possible model:

[image]

Because the reference is usually a low-voltage value, e.g. 2.5 V or 1.2 V, the system permanently compares a scaled-down version of the output voltage to that reference keeping the deviation or the error between the two at the lowest possible level. By construction, the reference voltage is a precise and stable value, insensitive to external perturbations like input voltage, temperature variations or output current. These external contributors are modeled as perturbations in the model I shown. You understand that if the output current changes or if the input voltage undergoes transients, the reference voltage must keep the same precise level to impose a constant voltage on the output.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is a bandgap voltage  that is temperature stable inside the chip for comparing a ratio of the output voltage in order to null this error. The LM317 uses 1.25V for ADJ voltage as Vref. Lower voltages are possible and used in SMPS IC's and ADC's and called FB or Vref.

All diodes have a linear NTC negative tempco and partially saturating transistors have smaller PTC due to the difference in the forward bias currents that produce Vcb and Vbe to create Vce and lower hFE.

When a transistor current mirror is used with a resistor in a differential amplifier the PTC effects can nulled by modulating this differential amplifier and creates this 1.23V to which is compensated by 65mV with a FET resistance at this low current to make the best linear temperature correction reference voltage.

This was invented by Bob Widler about 50 yrs ago after it was mathematically discovered to relate to Silicon electron voltage. This reduces the 1st order "thermometer effect" to < 20 ppm over a 100'C range. Today circuits exist to also null the smaller second order parabolic effects of temperature in order to have an even more accurate voltage reference.

In the future different designs will be even better at lower voltage using current references.

Answer (score 0):

> *What is "Reference"*

It's no different in principle to the scenario: -

[image]

"Reference" is basically a signal that represents what is needed at the output.